# Eager load full chain of self relations in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm, python-asyncio

Let's say I have a model which contains relation to itself, for example:

```py
Base = declarative_base()
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key = True)
    prev_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(id))
    prev = relationship('Node', uselist = False, lazy = 'joined')
```

Here I defined relation with "joined" eager loading technique; however, no matter which technique is chosen, unless "join_depth" is defined it will be, like, ignored. Of course, this is kinda expected behavior, but it's not what I need.

The general idea is to load all `prev` objects chain recursively by one query. And I know that not every database supports recursive selects, but PostgreSQL, which is one used by me, does. The query will look like:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE nodes_chain AS (
    SELECT entry.id, entry.prev_id
    FROM nodes entry
    WHERE entry.id = %
    UNION
    SELECT nodes.id, nodes.prev_id
    FROM nodes
    JOIN nodes_chain
    ON nodes.id = nodes_chain.prev_id
)
SELECT * from nodes_chain
```

And of course I can just write that query manually, like [in that guide](https://sanjayasubedi.com.np/python/sqlalchemy/recursive-query-in-postgresql-with-sqlalchemy/). But I'd like to define everything at ORM level to tell SQLAlchemy to perform it each time for loading `Node` objects. For example, to make it work in cases where `Node` itself have been selected as relation of another model, and many other situations.